# orgmode latex export: alternative to \newpage?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

In orgmode, is there a property I can set to a section that will output a pagebreak before it?

Right now, I can do the following:

```
* Section 1

** Subsection 1
stuff

** Subsection 2
stuff

\newpage

* Section 2
```

but when I hide/show subtrees, the `\newpage` is treated as part of Subsection 2 when it is really part of Section 2.

I would like to include the pagebreak in a property drawer related to Section 2, i.e.,

```
* Section 1

** Subsection 1
stuff

** Subsection 2
stuff

* Section 2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :pagebreak: \newpage
  :END:
```

or something similar. Does such a property exist?

Comment: I don't think so.